# Is it possible with KSQL to copy data from one Kafka cluster to another Kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I want to copy some data(logs) of a topic  **TOPIC_1** from Kafka **Cluster A** to another Kafka **Cluster B** based on some condition. Is it possible to do so using **KSQL**?
I don't want to use MirrorMaker since I don't want to copy all data and topics. Basically what I am asking is if there is a way to configure the cluster name along with the topic name also in the below command within the ***WITH clause***.

```
CREATE STREAM INPUT_STREAM (viewtime bigint, userid varchar, pageid varchar) WITH (kafka_topic='pageviews', value_format='DELIMITED');
```

If this is not possible with KSQL is there any other way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the KSQL properties, only one boostrap server can be connected to.

You would instead need to create a MirrorMaker / Confluent Replicator connector from another cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
If I am correct this will get all the data from a topic or cluster.
I only want a few logs from a given topic. Like for every 10000 logs in TOPIC1 in CLUSTER_A I want to push 1 log to TOPIC2 inn CLUSTER_B.

Is that possible ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any such processor out of the box that can do that. You'd have to write a custom consumer with multiple producers sending data to those other clusters